# Append unique fingerprint to file

Tags: python, windows, bash, powershell, jenkins

I have a set of files (compiled software) that I want to give an unique fingerprint before distribution. The idea is to write a script that:

1. Randomly generates a character sequence
2. Appends the character sequence to a file in the project
3. Stores the fingerprint in a database with the addressee
4. Distributes the software to the addressee

The requirements for the fingerprint process is that:

- The fingerprint is difficult to detect (i.e. not stored in the file metadata or easily accessible areas)
- The fingerprint does not corrupt the data of the file the sequence is added to
- The fingerprint can be added to an executable or dll file
- It's easy to read the fingerprint if you know where to look

Are there any open source solutions that is built for the purpose of fingerprinting files?

Comment: Good luck with that. Even if there were existing solutions, software recommendations are off-topic on stackoverflow. We are here to help you with specific problems that you have with code that you write.

Comment: The question is regarding code, utilizing a library or a tool to fingerpint files.

Comment: Any reason you don't just use a normal MD5 or SHA1 hash?

Comment: And what specific problem are you having with the code that you have written?

Comment: @JamesC. - If I understand the OP wants to append bits to the file that are unique to that file and obfuscated. Just adding the file hash would first alter the filehash and second be trivial for someone else to do.

Comment: If the hash is used for verification I don't see a need to append it to each file when it's also stored in a db. If not a simple hash then code signing with a certificate would be my next goto to verify file integrity.

Comment: @EBGreen I have this: `bytes_read = open("filename", "rb").read()`. Now what would be the best way of adding a fingerprint to this file?

Comment: Well, first you should edit your question. Second, There really isn't any way to add bits to the file in such a way that it doesn't corrupt binary files without adding it to the file's metadata or alternate data streams. I'm happy to be proven wrong though. Perhaps it would help if you explain why you want to do this. I assume it is for licensing reasons?

Comment: maybe you can look at this objects : [UUID](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/uuid.html)

Comment: I'm voting to close as too broad, because even though the solution requires code, you aren't asking about a specific implementation you have in mind, but ideas for protocols to implement in the first place. [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/) might be a better place to ask for this. Also, the fingerprint being difficult to detect but easy to read if you know where to look for is kind of inconsistent and implies security through obscurity. What problem are you even trying to solve?

Answer (score 1):

Storing information in the file without corrupting it and in a way that is not easily detectable is an exercise in [steganography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steganography), and quite a hard one. This theoretical tool needs to be able to parse executable structure, and properly modify it, edit offsets if needed, or detect padding arias, or basically do some of the work that the compiler is doing. I doubt that it exists or is reliable.

However, there are quite a few steganography tools that can store information in pictures by subtly changing the colors of the pixels, perhaps you can store your information in the icon of the exe file or any included asset.

Another way is to hide the data at compilation time, in optimization level of the performance-uncritical parts of the executable, so that compiler generates slightly different code, but the behavior is guaranteed to stay consistent. You can now use file hashes as your fingerprint.

Yet another way is to just create unused string inside some random function, mark it as `volatile` or analog in your language of choice to prevent the compiler from optimizing it out of your program and put something noticeable in it, like `REPLACE_ME`. Now you can open this file, search for this string and replace it with the identifier that you have generated. If identifier and the string were the same length - you can’t damage your software.

Another, more subtle way is to create multiple different rephrasings of the same messages in your app and swap them in and out as a way to differentiate versions. If your programming language stores null-terminated strings then this is very easy, just make your strings in the code as long as the longest rephrasing. If your language stores length of the string then you have to dynamically recalculate it too.

Alternatively, if you are working with the Unicode strings in your code, then you can use similar-looking glyphs in some strings as a less effort version of previous idea. Basically you are performing a [homograph attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDN_homograph_attack) on your strings. Alternatively you can use unicode control chars (ZWJ, ZWNJ, etc.) that do not affect most languages and are invisible.

All schemes is easily discovered by diffing two different distributions of the software, the one with the different optimization levels could be plausibly written off as just different builds of the software, but the persistent attacker still could figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are talking about compiled software, maybe an alternative solution could be to use an execbinary encrypting tool. When you execute the file it will ask for a password, if it's correct then it will use the password to generate a key. Then it uses that key to decrypt the program directly in memory. That way they won't be able to analyze the binary and even with the key it would be a lot more difficult to do so, much less modify it. You can put as many fingerprints as you like, regular text strings, into the code and they will most likely stay there.

Comment: You can’t really protect the program against the analysis if the user can execute it. Reverse engineering capable programmer can right-click -> create dump in task manager and get unencrypted binary. If you want to make it difficult to analyze - decrypt parts of the binary as they are needed for execution and re-encrypt after that, use obfuscation and multiple (tens) nested virtual machines. In this game you want to make RE so annoying that the hacker would give up, and it’s obviously doesn’t work with determined attackers.

Answer (score 0):

Well...

...the days of secrecy and secret espionage of world war II are over, and nowadays more easily found in many famous movies such as 2014 "The Imitation Game" with [Benedict Cumberbatch](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm1212722/?ref_=tt_cl_t_1) playing "Alan Turing" and [Keira Knightley](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm0461136/?ref_=tt_cl_t_2) as "Joan Clarke" are all awesome movies to see and see again.

One key conclusion that is possible to understand when watching and studying such matters is, a secret, an unbreakable message is impossible to achieve. So, in the 60s, and 70s mathematicians and cryptologists opted instead to deliver secret, unique messages with a time expiration date, that is to say, use time-dependent algorithms to hash a unique fingerprint ID (or message). Nowadays the most common usage of such algorithms is found on [Google Authenticator App](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Authenticator). This one in particular uses Time-based One-time Password Algorithm (TOTP; specified in RFC 6238) and HMAC-based One-time Password algorithm (HOTP; specified in RFC 4226.

**My introduction above is with purpose, one of raising awareness among software engineers about exaggeration in the usage of encryption and encryption algorithms to deliver software solutions.**

From what I read from your question, you don't need such elaborate solutions to "protect" your software. And I'm abusing here the definition of protection since we all know how that went with Microsoft products, in particular, MS-DOS 7 and Windows Products since the '90s. thirty years ago or so.

In reality, you already have a "unique Fingerprint ID" on each of your software solutions. And that Fingerprint is the software code itself plus the executable byte code.

Nothing is said in your question above about the size limits you have on your "encryption hash". So let's assume you want a "unique Fingerprint ID" with 256 max chars, You simply need to hash your programming source code with the corresponding byte code to generate a 256 chars hash string.

**No need to complicate your software solutions or make it more CPU intensive due to unnecessary encryption.**

One of many ways of doing "authenticity validation" is to load the byte code from the executable itself, to determine the corresponding "hash string", and then add it to the hash of the corresponding programming source code, previously added when programming the software solution and before generating the executable byte code.